# TiddlyWiki Mono theme colors issue

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

Hi All TiddlyWiki fans,

I have an issue with Mono theme for Tiddlywiki - http://j.d.mono.tiddlyspot.com/
When any plugin selected it isn't readable. Moreover It can't be fixed with any color palettes.

[image]

Also this problem happens when I use Tiddlytool TagCloud - https://tiddlytools.com/filtergenerators.html#TiddlyTools%2FFilterGenerators%2FTagCloud with Mono theme.

[image]

Do anyone have any idea how it can be soled?

Thank you in advance!